# How do I generate a CSV reader/writer for a type in F#?

Tags: csv, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm using the type providers from the `FSharp.Data` library to generate types for the expected JSON responses I'm getting back from a web service call. This works very well when I'm generating them from a sample JSON file, such as:

```
type User = JsonProvider<"data/user.sample.json">
```

What I'd like to do is generate something that can read and write a CSV representation of a type I've defined in F#. The `CsvProvider` doesn't seem to fit the bill, as like the `JsonProvider`, it seems to be for the case where I'm *starting* with a CSV file and want to generate a type, whereas I want something that goes in the reverse direction.

It doesn't seem like it would be too difficult to roll this myself using [the CsvFile module](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-csvfile.html), but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr**
the answer is: no there is no better way
**/tldr**

In general you have the set of data and you want to serialize this set of data, but wants to control how to serialize the data, without controlling it?

Wut?

So:

Just serialize the data you have. And if you have any preferences on how it should be serialized (json, xml, csv, other) you have somewhat to get your hands dirty and actually decide something, and possibly even have to write code to handle it.

OK, json, xml are "easy" and more or less working out of the box until you hit some "special" case and have to make sure it still works by adding attributes and what not.

Serializing to csv is OTOH nothing other than aggregating all records of data into one string with some separator and then write each line to file.

**Edit/addendum:**

After some more thinking about this and with the main question "what do you actually want to do?", I think that maybe the "confusion" might be that the type provider is some super-serializer. And its not.

I did try to follow up on creating a "new" csv with adding some data and that works kind of fine, but as you say you need to have some file format apriori, and that file format is "locked".

You might be able to do something like (which I do not think in anyway should be used):

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.0\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let csvstring = @"Column1;Column2;Column3
Stringinfo;123;20150331"

type SomeCSV = CsvProvider< csvstring, Separators=";", HasHeaders=true >

let csv = SomeCSV.GetSample().Truncate(0)
let rows = 
 seq
   {
    yield SomeCSV.Row("colum1", 111, 20150330 )
   }

let csvmodded = csv.Append rows

csvmodded.Save(@"c:\temp\csttestmodded.csv")
```

And after rereading all your comments and original postings once more, Im pretty sure what you want is "serializing" (or "deserializing"). Not typeproviders.

TypeProviders is for consuming something you do not have entirely control over format/serialization (not really true either, but lets go with that for now), especially things like CSV, XML (without XSDs), JSON, where you are not "owning" the original "data format" (what I guess you call POCO).

If you do have your POCOs and want to give this data to someone else, its generally not for a typeprovider to handle the serializing (but maybe for deserializing in consuming end).

Im not sure this edit clarified much (even for me! ;-)

Comment: I'll accept your answer because I believe at least your TL;DR is right. I hope you're not suggesting that this is impossible though. After all, the `BinaryFormatter` in .NET does exactly this (given only a POCO, transforms that POCO to and from a serialized form), just in binary rather than CSV or JSON.

Comment: Which is what Im meaning in "serialize the data you have". It is of course possible to serialize to JSON also, given some serializable object.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I probably shouldn't have mentioned type providers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to define the structure of the expected JSON yourself? That can be easily achieved with `FSharp.Data`. Below an example to get gold prices for last couple of days.

First you define the expected structure. Here `date` and `price`. Then you just use it to parse your data.

```
type Gold = JsonProvider<"""{ "date":"2015-03-20", "price":1171.75}""">
let goldPrcs = Gold.Parse goldPrcJson
```

And these are my sample data:

```
let goldPrcJson = """[["2015-03-20",1171.75],["2015-03-19",1164.0],["2015-03-18",1149.0],...]"""
```

and first results:

```
[
 [
   "2015-03-20",
   1171.75
 ],
 [
   "2015-03-19",
   1164.0
 ],
 [
   "2015-03-18",
   1149.0
 ],
 ...
]
```

Similar approach can be applied to CSV as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem materially different from just referencing a file that contains the sample JSON. What I was looking for is more of a "code first" solution. So given that I already have a type `type Gold = { date: DateTime; price:Decimal };`, somehow generate a format that can be used to serialize it to disk (in CSV or JSON or whatever).

Comment: I thought you asked for creating it manually, in case for example, when there is no sample available, like in my example where you only have row data. Plus it gives you some flexibility when you want to override header names.